# Find controller name from AuthenticateRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

In my `web.config` I have `configuration` -> `system.webServer` -> `modules` and have added a module named `BasicAuthHttpModule`. This has an `Init` event which assigns a `AuthenticateRequest` handler.

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
   context.AuthenticateRequest += OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
   context.EndRequest += OnApplicationEndRequest;
}

private static void OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // Find the controller name here
   var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
}
```

In the code above the `OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest` checks the `request.Headers["Authorization"]` and ensures that the user is valid. I do **not** want this to happen for a specific controller though. I tried adding the `AllowAnonymous` attribute to it and its methods. No changes.

How do I find the controller? The `RequestContext.RouteData` doesn't contain anything. I could look in the requested URL but I don't want to parse this like a string. Seems hacky. Also, *server/ControllerWithoutAccess/Index?ControllerWithAccess=1* would contain the name of the controller allowing anonymous access but would actually reference a different controller.

**[Edit]:** `((System.Web.HttpApplication)sender).Context.Request` points to my `request` variable in code. They are the same. Meanwhile, `request.RequestContext.RouteData` has a null `Route`, null `RouteHandler` and `Values` contains 0 items.

Comment: Nope. As I said, the RequestContext.RouteData has nothing in it

Comment: Indeed. So `sender` is actually an instance of `HttpApplication`, so you could look at *its* `Context` property, which should be the HttpContext for the current request. I wouldn't think the two are different though.

Comment: I updated the question with this information.

Comment: Try wrapping the context up in a new `RouteData`: `var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(((HttpApplication)sender).Context)); var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];` If that works I'll change this into an answer.

Comment: That did it! I had tried this in my watch window a while back based on a different post but it wouldn't evaluate. The issue was that I didn't have System.Web.Routing in my using area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you seem to have missing `Route` details, I think you'll just have to recreate the routing table based on the current context:

```
private static void OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
    var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(context)); 
    var controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"];
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind that this event is probably going to fire for every image, CSS, script file as well, so it could be an expensive operation. You may want to interrogate the request context more to make an intelligent decision about whether you need to be running the more expensive code.